# Ruby On Rails - undefined method `has_secure_password' for ActiveRecord:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Context - I am creating a simple authentication, following the line by line instruction from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hw6WtWJwRtU.

Steps completed so far -

1. Created a User Table. The table has columns user_name and password_digest
2. In User model mentioned 'has_secure_password'
3. Uncommented bcrypt in gemfile and executed bundle install
4. Created a controller sessions, created a new method 'Create' that has form to get username and password.

Error - On entering the user name and passowrd in the login form, I am getting error No method defined.

Steps taken so far to correct - 
1. Checked the table schema, the table has column password_digest and column type is varchar
2. gem list - mentions that bcrypt is installed. I closed rails server and restarted again too.

Please find the snippet -

User Model -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::
  attr_accessible :user_name, :password
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :UserType

  def find_by_name(name)
    user = User.find_by(user_name: name)
  end
end
```

Sessions Controller -

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_name(params[:user_name])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged In"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render new
    end
  end
end
```

Session View -

```
<h1>Log In</h1>

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :user_name %>
    <%= text_field_tag :user_name, params[:user_name] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="action"><%= submit_tag "Log In" %></div>
<%end%>
```

users table -

```
CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "user_name" varchar, "password_digest" varchar, "UserType_id" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX "index_users_on_UserType_id" ON "users" ("UserType_id");
```

Routes -

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :sessions
  resources :feedback_details
  resources :users
  resources :meetings
  resources :user_types
  root 'sessions#new'
```

Error Log -

```
Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-29 14:24:43 +0530
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BvROFNObaYS/8Fq8wjTLwh6DiWo5rcLNnfvpdhlxgD2vhEmx2ErXWJRA8ku6bHYBRZ8W2imI2N/+SMMlnuWz+w==", "user_name"=>"tushar", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log In"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `has_secure_password' for ActiveRecord:Module):
  app/models/user.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (8.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (31.6ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (25.3ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.8ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (51.1ms)
```

Please let me know, if I need to provide more information.

Comment: `class User < ActiveRecord::` is this correct in your User model? It should be `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: @HassaninAhmed, I was looking at all the wrong places. Thank you!

Comment: No worries :D Can I convert that to the answer?

Comment: @HassaninAhmed Yes please.

Comment: Good effort in trying to debug it yourself +1. Get some rest!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a teeny bit of code here.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```